# Neural network activation function

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

im fairly new to neural networks.
I want to ask what exactly does the activation output, is it the probability the combined summation of inputs and weights lead to a match for the next neuron?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The goal of activation functions is to introduce **non-linearity** in the neural network, so it can learn beyond linear relations between input and outputs.

As stated in your image, each neuron output is a linear combination of inputs + a bias, and then all this is sent into a non-linear function (activation function). This allow the network to learn complex relations between input ans outputs.

Most used activation function is ReLU, which is not a probability as it can return a value greater than 1.